# Show M values on mappoint /mouseover on a polyline - ArcGIS Server 10

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I want to show the M values i.e the chainage of the road when I move my mouse over it.

I am using mappoint to show some static attributes but I also want to show the dynamic M values along the road when I mouse my mouse pointer over it..

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Silverlight API 2.2 and ArcGIS Silverlight 10

Please guide...